# How to turn on "Release & Allow Sender", and "Block" from End-user spam notifications in EOP

Tags: spam, microsoft-office-365

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/configure-end-user-spam-notifications-in-exchange-online states that the spam notification report to users provides the following choices:

"
**Preview** the message if you would like to preview the content or header prior to taking action.

**Download** the message if you would like to review the message and attachments (if any) on your device prior to taking action.

**Release** if the message isn’t spam and you want Office 365 to send the message to your mailbox.

**Release & Allow Sender** if the message isn’t spam and you want Office 365 to add the sender to your safe senders and recipients list for future emails. Keep in mind that your admin may have other organization wide allow/block configurations that override your safe sender list.

**Release & Report**, if the message isn’t spam and you want to send the message to your mailbox and report it to Microsoft for analysis.

**Block** if you want Office 365 to add the sender to your blocked senders list.
"

But as can be seen from the below screenshot I keep finding like examples of on the internet, which contain just the slightly differently worded 'Release' & 'Release & Report' options, like what we are currently getting from our O365/Exchange 2010 hybrid setup's spam notification report to users.

*Does one have to turn on the extra options? If so, where does one do this?*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This change is rolling out at the current time. Supposedly it was announced before Christmas 2018 in the Message Center, but I have not seen this announcement (MC170244). When the new features reach your tenant (and you cannot do anything to change this) you and your users will get the new email notification.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe MS would leave people without some vital functionality, to some companies, for 3 whole months. We moved onto a better spam solution...